# Error al querer instanciar objetos con un constructor de 7 parámetros en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, constructor

Tengo una clase Pelicula dentro de un paquete ObjetosNegocio_233293 en un proyecto "ObjetosNegocio_233293", y tengo otra clase llamada Prueba2 dentro de un paquete Pruebas en un proyecto "Pruebas_233293", ahora bien en mi clase de Pruaba2 estoy tratando de crear una instancia de un objeto de tipo Pelicula, de la siguiente manera:

package Pruebas;

import ObjetosNegocio_233293.Pelicula;
import ObjetosNegocio_233293.Articulo;

public class Prueba2 {

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    
    Pelicula pelicula1 = new Pelicula("Colin Firth","Anna Chancellor","BBC","P00001","Orgullo y prejuicio","Drama","A");
    
}
```

}

Para crear este objeto estoy tratando de utilizar un constructor que recibe 7 parámetros, todos de tipo String, el cual mostraré más adelante ya que enseñe el codigo de la clase Pelicula, como pueden ver ya hice los import necesarios tanto de Pelicula y de Articulo también por si acaso, ya que la clase Pelicula hereda de otra llamada Articulo, mi clase Pelicula tiene estos constructores:

package ObjetosNegocio_233293;

public class Pelicula extends Articulo{

```
private String actor1;
private String actor2;
private String productora;

public Pelicula() {
}

public Pelicula(String actor1, String actor2, String productora, String numCatalogo, String titulo, String genero, String clasificacion) {
    super(numCatalogo, titulo, genero, clasificacion);
    this.actor1 = actor1;
    this.actor2 = actor2;
    this.productora = productora;
}

public Pelicula(String numCatalogo) {
    super(numCatalogo);
}
```

Como dije, estoy intentando usar el segundo que estoy mostrando, pero me arroja el siguiente error dentro de mi clase Prueba2:

no suitable constructor found for Pelicula(String,String,String,String,String,String,String)
constructor Pelicula.Pelicula() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Pelicula.Pelicula(String,String,String,String,String,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Pelicula.Pelicula(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Lo que me resulta curioso es que el mensaje de error me reconoce el constructor por omision y el que recibe un string, pero el que a mi me interesa (que se supone es de 7 parametros) lo reconoce como si fuera de 6, ya me aseguré de agregar las referencias que sean necesarias, de compilar el proyecto de ObjetosNegocio_233293, todas las clases están en los paquetes que deberían y los argumentos están bien redactados (son 7 en total y todos String)

Comment: De casualidad, dentro de Prueba2 tienes definida la clase Pelicula?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error:

> no suitable constructor found for
> Pelicula(String,String,String,String,String,String,String) constructor
> Pelicula.Pelicula() is not applicable (actual and formal argument
> lists differ in length) constructor
> Pelicula.Pelicula(String,String,String,String,String,String) is not
> applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> constructor Pelicula.Pelicula(String) is not applicable (actual and
> formal argument lists differ in length)

Estas tratano de usar un constructor "inadecuado", pero revisando tu código, desde la clase `Prueba2` estas instanciando a `Pelicula` :

```
public class Prueba2 {

public static void main (String args[]){
    
    Pelicula pelicula1 = new Pelicula("Colin Firth","Anna Chancellor","BBC","P00001","Orgullo y prejuicio","Drama","A");
    
  }
}
```

y la clase Pelicula tiene un constructor adecuado para estos 7 para metros de tipo `String` :

```
public Pelicula(String actor1, String actor2, String productora, String numCatalogo, String titulo, String genero, String clasificacion) {
    super(numCatalogo, titulo, genero, clasificacion);
    this.actor1 = actor1;
    this.actor2 = actor2;
    this.productora = productora;
}
```

Revisando el código y los paquetes donde se encuentran estas clases, me parece que en este caso el problema es simplemente de sincronización de tu IDE, te sugiero limpiar y volver a generar tu proyecto, puedes reiniciar tu IDE y tratar nuevamente.